# Can i change CSS of existing magento extention?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

can i take existing magento extension to local to prevent updating and 
can i change it's UI by changing the CSS.
If yes how to do it?
i'm looking to change existing magento community edition extention

Comment: Explain your question in detail

Comment: i want to install http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-select-in-layered-navigation-filters.html

and change it's css with different colors and different fonts

Comment: add css in styles.css of your current theme.